# How do I remove delay in dhclient after DHCPNAK?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhclient, delay

After moving to new AP, I restart `dhclient` to switch to the new network:

```
DHCPREQUEST on <interface> to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from <new router IP>
<delay>
DHCPDISCOVER on <interface> to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPREQUEST on <interface> to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPOFFER from <new router IP>
DHCPACK from <new router IP>
```

How do I avoid the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly release the lease prior to acquiring a new one:

```
dhclient -r
dhclient -d wlan0
```